# Getting JSESSIONID cookie value in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, spring-security

As you can see in firefox I can see my cookie.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGA7L.png)

Oh well but when I check: document.cookie in console I get nothing:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ0Pt.png)

I need to get the value of the JSESSIONID and store it for some reasons. Can someone give me an advice?

Comment: domains are not the same?

Comment: "store it for some reasons" — What are those reasons?

Comment: well I made the domains equal but still nothing...  Both now are 'localhost'

Comment: @Quentin I was going to use it for saving the session of a user if he shut downs the app(not hit the HOME button but if he kills it)  without loggin out. I am using some push notification and stuff which are different for each user lets say and I want the user to get them even if he has closed his app.

Answer (score 0):

You have different domains on those screenshots. You can share cookies cross subdomain only.

Comment: I just made the domains euql but still nothing. Both now are 'localhost'

Comment: try to open hosts file and add domain name to your localhost. for example: 127.0.0.1 mysite after go to http://mysite and try cookie there. I had the same problem and i could resolve it so.